# Why was this question flagged as too broad, and how can I improve on it?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435369/how-to-modify-a-word-document-using-python) was flagged as too broad. My issue is that I don't know how to make it more specific. I would appreciate suggestions for more info that I can provide, but honestly the question seems as specific as any other question I've asked before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Overflow (and much of the rest of Stack Exchange) works best when there is a single, answerable question in the post.

Taking the key sentences from this:

> What I'm looking to do is create many new Word documents by modifying an existing document. Here's a rough sketch of what I'm trying to accomplish. ... How can I do this?

As this is written, it appears you are asking for someone to design the entirety of the code for you.  That is why it is too broad.

Instead, the questions that Stack Overflow works best for would be something more along the lines of:

> I'm trying to create word documents from an existing word template.  So far, I have have written code that opens up the file and identifies the title in the document.
>
> ```
> <<insert code here>>
> ```
>
> However, when I start trying to read the actual contents of the file and print it out to see that I have the correct data, I get something very wrong.
>
> ```
> <<insert what you expect>>
>
> <<insert output>>
> ```
>
> This is built from a file using Microsoft Word with the contents ... or you can also find the corresponding .rtf file zipped and base64 encoded at the following gist

Note, that this shows what you have done, the specific problem you are encountering in the code that can be answered and the necessary steps to reproduce the error for someone to be able to help you in the event that it isn't obvious from looking at the code what you are doing wrong.